# Refining a Daily Sales Forecast

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I am currently in the process of attempting to refine a daily sales forecast for my employer. I am generating this forecast using a time series in R with an ARIMA model, and the MAPE is currently around 12%.

I'd ideally like to be able to integrate some additional categorical variables to refine the forecast further (e.g. new product launches; promotional activity etc.) but am unsure of how best to achieve this as most examples online use numerical predictors within a regression model.

If possible, I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me out with regards to successfully incorporating non-numerical variables into my forecast? If anyone also has any additional tips about good ways to refine a daily forecast then these ideas would also be very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `ARIMAX` which allows external variable. For categorical you need to convert them using `model.matrix()`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!